# Having trouble finding maximum average in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having an issue with an SQL query.

Essentially, I am trying to find the maximum average value for a group.

This is what I've written:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT BRAND_NAME AS AVG_BRAND, AVG(PROD_PRICE) 
AS AVG_PRICE FROM LGPRODUCT AS PROD, LGBRAND AS BRAND 
WHERE PROD.BRAND_ID=BRAND.BRAND_ID GROUP BY PROD.BRAND_ID) AS AVG_GROUP
WHERE AVG_PRICE=MAX(AVG_PRICE);
```

This is what the subquery returns:

[image: This is what the subquery returns]

I can retrieve AVG_PRICE and MAX(AVG_PRICE). I can even do WHERE statements such as:

```
WHERE AVG_PRICE>20
```

And that works. When I run my query though I get an error code 1111.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`.

Comment: Simply moving that `WHERE` clause to a `HAVING` clause won't work here, although it will get you closer. Instead, take that subquery out and stick `ORDER BY AVG_PRICE DESC LIMIT 1` at the end of it and rerun (just the subquery)

Comment: I don't think this is just a `HAVING` versus `WHERE` issue.  If you notice, the solution I'm proposing has neither `HAVING` nor `WHERE`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT BRAND_NAME AS AVG_BRAND, AVG(PROD_PRICE) AS AVG_PRICE
FROM LGPRODUCT PROD JOIN
     LGBRAND BRAND 
     ON PROD.BRAND_ID = BRAND.BRAND_ID
GROUP BY PROD.BRAND_ID
ORDER BY AVG_PRICE DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Snuck that in before the Barmar's Mjölnir fell. +1